# How can I click the button to see more values using Selenium Python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium, web-scraping

```
from selenium import webdriver
import time
import datetime

driver = webdriver.Chrome(
executable_path=r'C:\Users\Kashi\Downloads\Compressed\chromedriver_win32/chromedriver.exe')
driver.get('https://www.mql5.com/en/quotes/currencies')
driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="list-view-btn"]').click()
time.sleep(2)
driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="symbols_more"]').click()
```

I'm unable to click on the button "More Symbols". I've tried the upper method but I can't. Please help me to click on the button "More Symbols", as I'm able to click on the list view button but I'm getting an error on the 2nd one.

```
ElementClickInterceptedException: Message: element click intercepted: Element <a id="symbols_more" class="button button_green" href="#" onclick="return Navigator.Overview.loadMore(this, 1);">...</a> is not clickable at point (644, 550). Other element would receive the click: <a href="/en/about/cookies">...</a>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are not handling the cookies which is obscuring your target element.

```
#Close the Cookies element
driver.find_element_by_xpath("//div[@id='floatVerticalPanel']/span").click()

driver.find_element_by_xpath("//*[@id='list-view-btn']").click()
#Add a wait time for the page to load
driver.find_element_by_xpath("//a[@id='symbols_more']").click()
```